# pnp/sp how to return user information after creating a list item?

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

I am creating an SPFX webpart and i have to call pnp/sp to check if a list item exist and if it isn't i will create a new list item. this is my code for creating a new list item:

```
 return sp.web.lists.getByTitle(qnaListTrackingListName).items.add({
                LastUpdated: d.toDateString(),
                LastPublished: null,
                LockedById: currentUser.Id,
                LockedReleaseTime: d.toDateString()
            }).then((result: ItemAddResult) => {
                console.log(result);
               return result.data;
            });
```

it creates my item successfully however i want it to return the list item details including the userfield ( i need the email). currently it is only returning the id. how do i expand it to include the email address as well?

return:

```
GUID: "64797cb7-9c7c-408e-b848-d899440ea634"
ID: 19
Id: 19
LastPublished: null
LastUpdated: "2018-09-24T16:00:00Z"
LockedById: 10
LockedByStringId: "10"
LockedReleaseTime: "2018-09-24T16:00:00Z"
Modified: "2018-09-25T15:45:09Z"
```

do i need to call a get get list item with filter and expand?

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [Github Page](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Basic--Operations):

> ```
> // this result will have two properties "data" and "item"
> // data is what was returned from SharePoint after the add operation
> // and item is an object of type item representing the REST query to that item
> // so you can immediately chain off that
> ```

Given that, what you're accessing is just the data property. If you need the details of the item, you need to use `result.item` instead.